# How to install LeafletJS plugin with an existing leaflet map

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have an existing leaflet map. You can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tn7u2RRYGbA5e9ueoxFfyVr6whnHf-9Q/view?usp=sharing)

Im not sure how to put this project into a fiddle for easier use so hopefully this link will suffice.

[Here](https://github.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol) is the plugin im trying to use with my existing map. (Im trying to go with the advanced controls)

There is some good documentation on how to install it but i cant quite get it working. I have tried included the dist folder.

What needs to be linked, then how do i replace the existing controls with the new controls? Im leaving the links and new control code not in my html to make it easier to see what im starting with.

It doesn't matter what groups and markers are in place. As i can change them later on im just trying to get something to work with the map i currently have in there.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/warrenbreedlove/5mbwjtr0/3/) is a fiddle with my current html. Hopefully to help make this easier to share code.

This is the links int he example html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Advanced Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.1/leaflet.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.1/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="../src/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js"></script>
  <script src="exampledata.js"></script>
  <script>
```

My current control panel:
[image]

The advanced control panel:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to download `leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.min.js` and `leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.min.css` from the GitHub Repository and save them somewhere in your Project.
For this example I chose a separate "Plugins"-Folder.

Next you will have to link both files in the `<head>`-section of your HTML-File. The project-documentation gets this wrong in its example because it links non-minified Files (`[...].js` instead of `[...].min.js`).
In my project this looks like this:

```
<script src="plugins/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.min.css"/>
```

To add the control to your map create an Overlay-Group and add the groupedLayers-Control to your map.

```
// Add Markers
var bandit_encampment_1 = L.marker([-48, -55]).bindPopup('<b>Bandit Encampment</b>');
var farbane_woods_portal = L.marker([-46,-31.5]).bindPopup('<b>Farbane Woods Portal</b>');

var town_1 = L.marker([-47,-31.5]).bindPopup('<b>Stadt Alpha</b>');
var town_2 = L.marker([-48,-31.5]).bindPopup('<b>Stadt Bravo</b>');

// Group Markers
var mg_bandit_encampments = L.layerGroup([bandit_encampment_1]);
var mg_rift_portals = L.layerGroup([farbane_woods_portal]);
var mg_towns = L.layerGroup([town_1, town_2]);

// Create the Overlay-Group with your structure
var groupedOverlays = {
  "Points of Interest": {
    "Bandit Encampments" : mg_bandit_encampments,
    "Rift Portals" : mg_rift_portals,
  },
  "Geography": {
    "Towns": mg_towns
  }
};

// Add the control
L.control.groupedLayers(null, groupedOverlays).addTo(map);
```

I have provided a working example based on your JS-Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/8ez4nwau/

Comment: Great answer! I got it working with my map as well! One more question. When you hover over the layers icon that shows the new controls. Is there a way to keep it in the hovered state? 

Basically where in the top right its just always showing the full control panel?

I feel that would be useful to see it always on desktop. On mobile it might be nice to be able to enlarge and minimize it.

Comment: Im trying to create something like this: https://pine.blackpinguin.de/ I beleive what they used here is a very modified version of the layer control plugin. This is kinda wha ti want my end product to be similar to.

Comment: Say iw anted to mess with the syling of the panel. Would i do that in leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.min.css?

Comment: @WarrenBreedlove The default Leaflet-Layer-Control behaves like this on mobile, I'd expect this one to do so as well. You should be able to modify it with JS or CSS if it doesnt. JS is probably easier - but I haven't worked with the plugin before, so I can't really give you a qualified answer to that question.

Comment: If you want to change the styling you could change it in the [...].css file or implement your own additional styling with CSS. You can see the names/ids/classes of the control-element with the Inspector of your browsers Dev-Tools. If you want to change anything in the plugins JS or CSS I'd advice you download the non-minified version (,js instead of .min.js) from the "src" folder of the plugins GitHub-Page.

Comment: Styling the Default-Layercontrol of Leaflet was a bit of a hassle in the past. I have reimplementet that Element from scratch for past projects, but I advise against this if it can be helped. Getting the Layer-Management to behave was not trivial.

Comment: What exactly is a minified version. Does it act the same as a non minified version? If i do want to edit the css should i just replace the minified ones with the non-minified ones then ill be able to edit those.

Comment: A minified file contains the same "logic" as a non-minified file, but is (programatically) optimized for size. It removes whitespaces and linebreaks and makes variable names or function names as short as possible. It is great for production because smaller files load faster - but it is no good for developing/debugging, as it is hard to read.